# What do you call those stuff published in craigslist.com?

Tags: word-choice, american-english

I was thinking about the word of those things which are published in craigslist.com and whether if I should call them ads? list? commercials? notice? promotion? flyers? or something else.

To clear what I say, where I live, there some daily extra pages published with newspapers in which people and organizations publish their needs or what they can offer other people, as one sells a car or another needs a teacher etc.

What are these kind of things called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ads offering or looking for products or services are commonly known as [*classified ads*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classified_ad):

> Classified advertisements [...] are mostly placed by private individuals with single items they wish to sell or buy.

or, as @Manoochehr added below, [*personal ads*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_advertisement) cover the sort of "looking for love" (for various values of "love") listings you also find.

These two should cover most of what you find on Craigslist. :)

Comment: Also personals, personal ads.

Comment: If the context is already established, someone might also refer to an ad as a "listing".